# Generate checkerboard superposition of two images

Tags: imagemagick

I would like to find a command that allows to combine two images (A.png and B.png) and generate a checkerboard superposition of the wo (like you can see below). I have searched ImageMagick and convert sites without success. If anybody has any tip, that would be fantastic. Thanks in advance, Chris.
[image: below]

Comment: What are the two images? Do you have a dark square and a light square or do you count the background as one of the two?

Comment: Each image are 64x64 and the content of these image can be completly different. I want to use : top row first left tile:  image A 8x8, top row second tile: image B 8x8, top row third tile image A 8x8, etc...

Answer (score 0):

This is easier than you might think. You don't need to do anything to the first image, then you take the second image and make transparent *"holes"* in it and overlay it onto the first.

I will use slightly different sizes from yours so it is easy to see what's going on.

First, make a mask. Make it as PNG to losslessly preserve exact pixel values:

```
magick -size 64x64 xc:black xc:white +append \( +clone -flop \) -append -write MPR:x -delete 0 -size 512x512 tile:MPR:x mask.png
```

[image]

Then make 2 sample images:

```
magick -size 512x512 -seed 42 plasma:tomato-steelblue -paint 20 -swirl 200 a.jpg
magick -size 512x512 gradient:black-magenta b.jpg
```

[image]

Now do the magic:

```
# Push mask.png into b.jpg as its transparency, then overlay onto a.jpg
magick a.jpg \( b.jpg mask.png -compose copyalpha -composite \) -compose over -composite result.png
```

[image]